# MYSQL returns MAXIMUM CONNECTION POOL error when I try to add more then hundred entries in one transaction

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have stock database application so where user enter all the items to a datagrid which is added to database later, but whenever the items are more than 100 items it returns error:

> Error connecting: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Here is the code:

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV_ITEMS.Rows

        If row.IsNewRow = False Then

            Dim ITEM_CODE_VAL As Double = row.Cells(1).Value
            Dim ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL = row.Cells(2).Value
            Dim ITEM_NAME_VAL = row.Cells(3).Value
            Dim ITEM_PRICE_VAL = row.Cells(4).Value
            Dim ITEM_DATE_VAL = row.Cells(5).Value

            'FOR CHECK IF SUPPLIER ALL READY EXISTS
            Dim CON1 As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; username=root; password=pwd; database=airtech_db;")
            Dim CMD1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `STOCK` where `ITEM_CODE`='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "';", con1)
            Dim dt1 As New DataTable
            Dim DR1 As MySqlDataReader
            CON1.Open()
            dt1.Clear()
            With dt1
                DR1 = CMD1.ExecuteReader
                DR1.Read()
                If DR1.HasRows = True Then
                    'MsgBox("Item already exists")
                    Call ADD_DATA_TO_EXISTING_RECORD(ITEM_CODE_VAL, ITEM_QUANTITY_VAL)
                    CON1.Close()
                Else
                    'Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring)
                    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Insert into `stock` values(null,@ITEM_CODE,@ITEM_NAME,@ITEM_PRICE,@ITEM_QUANTITY,@SALE_PRICE,@STOCK_DATE,'N/A');", con)
                        Try
                            Dim CON As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; username=root; password=pwd; database=airtech_db;")
                            con.Open()
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_CODE", row.Cells(1).Value)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_NAME", row.Cells(3).Value)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_PRICE", row.Cells(4).Value)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_QUANTITY", row.Cells(2).Value)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SALE_PRICE", row.Cells(5).Value)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STOCK_DATE", Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Finally
                            con.Close()
                        End Try

                    End Using
                    'End Using

                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: That sounds like a setting in MySQL (to increase the connection pool size). Is this database system under your administrative control?

Comment: yes I am the administrator but in the first place, once a entry has made why the connection didn't dispose properly, there isn't any way we can make all the entries either in one connection or connections can be closed after each entry is made,  so maximum pool size is not utilized

Comment: Is the code above in some kind of loop? TBH I feel the issue is coming from somewhere else, specifically connections/commands not being closed/disposed of. Also, the above *could* be done in one go to the DB as well.

Comment: Is it being called in parallel or async? Then that is your answer.

Comment: To follow on from @Codexer, I am looking at this code: `New MySqlConnection(constring)`. Are you creating a new connection every time you run this? If this is in a loop, can you create one connection and use it for every call here?

Comment: @halfer I agree, thanks for expanding on my comment.

Comment: thanks guys for the explanations, well thats in the loop of "each row" statement of datagridview as i said already user adds the items in the datagridview and then loop runs to add row by row data to the database

Comment: Could you expand your code sample to include the loop code?

Comment: @codexer you were absoultly right problem wasnt with this code or loop but the problem was coming from opening and closing the connections

Comment: @halfer as u said i just moved the connection string out of the loop and left the rest as it is it worked !! 
thanks guyz you are amazing

Comment: @halfer i edited the code in my question so you can see the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a query is made being in the loop, move the connection string out of the loop let the command and datareaders do the work inside the loop

e.g

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring)
        con.Open()
        'any for Loop you want to run

        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Insert into `stock` values(null,@ITEM_CODE,@ITEM_NAME,@ITEM_PRICE,@ITEM_QUANTITY,@SALE_PRICE,@STOCK_DATE,'N/A');", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_CODE", row.Cells(1).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_NAME", row.Cells(3).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_PRICE", row.Cells(4).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_QUANTITY", row.Cells(2).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SALE_PRICE", row.Cells(5).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STOCK_DATE", Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    Next
    con.Close()
```

Comment: open and close the connection out side of the loop is actual solution to this problem